# setPlayerHp() in Player cannot be applied to integer

Tags: java, android, class, integer

I'm writing a Text Adventure app for my course, and I've come across this error. I have a class named Player with three variabled associated (playerPos, playerHP and playerInv[])

When I try to get or set the value of playerHP from the Player class, I get the following:

"get/setPlayerHP cannot be applied to (int)"

I am confused as to why. Any suggestions?

```
    public class Player {

    private int playerPos;
    private int playerHP;
    private String playerInv[];

    Player(int startPos, int startHP, String[] newInventory[])
    {
        playerPos = startPos;
        playerHP = startHP;
        playerInv = newInventory[10];
    }

    public int getPlayerPos() {
        return playerPos;
    }

    public void setPlayerPos(int playerPos) {
        this.playerPos = playerPos;
    }

    public int getPlayerHP(){
        return playerHP;
    }

    public void setPlayerHP(){
        this.playerHP = playerPos;
    }

    public String setPlayerInv() {
        return playerInv[10];
    }

    public void setPlayerInv(String inventory) {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            this.playerInv[i] = playerInv[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the instance in which I am trying to use it:

```
    public void PyrronQ1()
{
    answerButton.setEnabled(true);
    questionText.setText("What is my favourite colour?");
    answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (answerText.getText().toString() == "Red")
            {
                PyrronQ2();
            }
            else
            {
                thePlayer.setPlayerHP(thePlayer.getPlayerHP() -20);
                if (thePlayer.getPlayerHP() <= 0)
                {
                    thePlayer.setPlayerPos(0);
                    setupControls();
                    RoomText.setText(thedungeon[thePlayer.getPlayerPos()].getName());
                    setupDirectionButtons();
                    thePlayer.setPlayerHP(100);


                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a method that takes no arguments:

```
public void setPlayerHP(){
    this.playerHP = playerPos;
}
```

Thus trying to pass an integer into this method will do nothing.

You likely want to add an argument to this method, such as:

```
public void setPlayerHP(int hp) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure you see what exactly is going on:

In your onClick() method here:

```
..
..
else
    {
        thePlayer.setPlayerHP(thePlayer.getPlayerHP() -20);
..
..
```

You are passing an int as an argument to the method setPlayerHP() in the player class but if you look back at the method definition:

```
public void setPlayerHP(){ 
    this.playerHP = playerPos;
}
```

You will see you have it defined with no parameters -- ie you haven't told it to take an int as an argument. Simply change it to

```
public void setPlayerHP(int hp) {
    this.playerHP = hp;
}
```

As @Matteo suggested above.

Generally setter methods as they are called, eg SetPlayerHp() etc will take an argument. If you think about it, you want some variable to be given some new value, it needs to get that new value some how right? There are other ways of course.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing:

```
public void setPlayerHP(){ 
    this.playerHP = playerPos;
}
```

I think it should be something like

```
public void setPlayerHP(int hp){ 
    this.playerHP = hp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method setPlayerHp has no arguments, so it's saying that the arguments requested (none) do not match (int). When calling setPlayerHp() with no arguments, all you're doing is setting playerHp to playerPos. You need to redefine it like this:

```
public void setPlayerHp(int playerHp) {
    this.playerHp = playerHp;
}
```